# Interpolate proportionally with duplicate index

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a table like
`df = pd.DataFrame([1,np.nan,3,1,np.nan,3,50,np.nan,52], index=[7, 8, 9, 7, 12, 27, 7, 8, 9])`:

```
index  values
7      1
8      NaN
9      3
7      1
12     NaN
27     3
7      50
8      NaN
9      52
```

Rows are correctly sorted. However, index here is not ordered, and has duplicates by design.

How to interpolate values here proportionally to index (method="index")?

If I try to interpolate using index, resulting Series is messed up because of duplicate index:
`df.interpolate(method='index')`:

```
index  values  desired  actual
7      1       1        1
8      NaN     2        2
9      3       3        3
7      1       1        1
12     NaN     1.5      52   <-- wat
27     3       3        3
7      50      50       50
8      NaN     51       1.1  <-- wat
9      52      52       52
```

If not reproducible: Pandas 0.23.3, Numpy: 1.14.5, Python: 3.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More complicated way if you have situation like I mentioned above in scott 's comment

```
np.where(df['values'].isnull(),df['values'].shift()+(df['values'].shift(-1)-df['values'].shift())*(df['index']-df['index'].shift())/(df['index'].shift(-1)-df['index'].shift()),df['values'])
Out[219]: array([ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  1. ,  1.5,  3. , 50. , 51. , 52. ])
```

This is to check the distance of each null value between two valid value , and fill the value with the distance of index(different).

tolerance : only one missing value between two values

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a grouping the dataframe based on index:

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_series().diff().lt(0).cumsum())\
  .apply(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='index'))
```

Output:

```
       0
7    1.0
8    2.0
9    3.0
7    1.0
12   1.5
27   3.0
7   50.0
8   51.0
9   52.0
```

Comment: How about change duplicate is not always increase index like 1 2 3 2 3 4 1 2 3

Comment: @Wen, we should be able to create groups on that too.

Comment: Just feel like this is hard to do without for loop , maybe we should consider 1 2 3 2 3 4 9 10 11

Comment: @Wen I do agree with you, a loop may be need  in that case.  Hopefully, you can control you index on input. :)

Comment: Still a nice approach :-)

Comment: adding a way for this problem , but may only work for linear

Comment: Thank you, I did that as my first attempt, but it estimated to work for 5 days on my 90m dataset. In my particular case, there could be only one `NaN` between values, so I did interpolation manually, using `shift(1)` etc. It worked in <10 seconds. However, for small dataframes `.apply()` would totally work.